# How do i check what values have been "joined"?

Tags: python, list

```py
def reduceLineLeft(xs): 
    def aux(acc, y):
        if len(acc) == 0: acc.append(y)
        elif acc[len(acc)-1] == y:
            acc[len(acc)-1] = y * 2
            acc.append(0)
        else: acc.append(y)
        return acc
    res = list(filter(lambda x: x !=0, reduce(aux, filter(lambda x: x!=0, xs), [])))
    res.extend([0 for i in range(0, len(xs)-len(res))])
    return res
```

This function takes a row of a 2D list and "joins" the items of the same value for example this list `[4, 2, 2, 0]` and squish it using the `reduceLineLeft` function it will return `[4, 4, 0, 0]`

[image: list before visualization]
[image: list after visualization]

How do i know what values have been "joined". In the example above i would want to know that the value `2` was joined, but if the values would be `[4, 4, 2, 2]` i would need it to return `[4, 2]` the list will look like this `[8, 4, 0, 0]` after the "join"

EDIT:
Here is a brief explanation on the "joining" of the values (tiles)

If two tiles of the same number collide while moving (when the function is run), they will merge into a tile with the total value of the two tiles that collided. The resulting tile cannot merge with another tile again in the same move (you have to run the function twice).

Comment: Your rule for joining isn't clear. In your first example, you seem to be reducing the pair `2, 2` to a single value `4` via addition. In your second example, you just seem to be absorbing duplicate values.

Comment: @chepner oh god. Sorry, that was a horrible typo on my part

Comment: You are still saying that `[4, 4, 2, 2]` becomes `[4, 2]` and after the "join" it will be `[8, 2, 0, 0]`???

Comment: You can always *store* the operands, rather than reducing them. (This is basically a situation involving [free monoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_monoid), if you want to dig into the theory.) Instead of reducing `[4, 2, 2, 0]` to `[4, 4, 0, 0]`, you reduce it to `[4, (2, 2), 0, 0]`. You can *display* `4 4` (adding 2 + 2 on demand) without *storing*  `4 4`.

Comment: @Tomerikoo i am not saying that [4, 4, 2, 2] becomes [4, 2] i am saying that i would need to know the values joined in this case they are [4, 2]

Comment: @chepner an example would be great

Comment: I am assuming you are doing something similar to the 2048 game. Then why would `[4, 4 ,2 ,2]` become `[8, 2, 0, 0]`? It should either be `[8, 4, 0, 0]`, `[4, 4, 4, 0]` or `[8, 2, 2, 0]` depending on how many "join"s you allow each iteration

Comment: @Tomerikoo yes i am making 2048. The `[8, 2, 0, 0]` was a typo

Comment: So don't you always know what numbers were joined? If you meet an `8`, you know it was `[8//2, 8//2]` if you meet a `4` ...

Comment: I don't know what additional example you would want. My point is that just because your *GUI* is displaying two 4s doesn't mean your underlying data structure must. (Put another way, the mapping from your data structure to your GUI display does not have to be strict. Perhaps let the join operation map `[4, 2, 2, 0]` to `[4, (2, 2), 0, 0]`, and let your display operation map `[4, (2, 2), 0, 0]` to `[4, 4, 0, 0]` before displaying each element of the result as a tile.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Tomerikoo for helping me find this answer.

To get the values that had been "joined" i go through them with a for loop and divide them by 2.

```py
s = 0
    for i in range(len(xs)):
        if res[i] == 0:
            continue;
        item = res[i]
        for j in range(len(xs)):
            if xs[j] == 0:
                continue
            if xs[j] == item//2:
                if len(xs) != j+1 and xs[j+1] == item//2:
                    # add score
                    s += item
                    xs[j] == 0
                    xs[j+1] == 0
                    break;
```

Let's break down what this code does.

1. Checks if the value we are on is not zero in the results
2. Then if isn't go through all the values on the original list
3. if the list provided item `j` is equal to the value divided by 2 basically it checks if this value was combined
4. If it was combined and the item next to it or later is the same add the value to the score

Comment: Probably should be `if item > 2:` though...